# /testfor in minecraft 14w11b (snapshot of 1.8)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I can't test for people's locations using @a[x=-563,y=4,z=23]. Instead, the redstone comparator will just turn on even if no one is at -563,4,23.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In 1.8, it is @a[x=-563,y=4,z=23,dx=0,dy=0,dz=0]

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying a maximum search radius, for example:

```
@a[x=-563,y=4,z=23,r=1]
```

Note that you can use this shortcut:

```
@a[-563,4,23,1]
```